# How to fix the "running '__rvm_make -j4'," error, while installing ruby 3.2.1 using RVM?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

Am trying to install ruby 3.2.1 using RVM. I'm getting the below error.

```
05:44:55 # rvm install ruby-3.2.1
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.6.5
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: oracle/6/x86_64/ruby-3.2.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for oracle.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.2.1 - #downloading ruby-3.2.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 19.5M  100 19.5M    0     0  20.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 29.5M
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-3.2.1 - #extracting ruby-3.2.1 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-3.2.1.....
ruby-3.2.1 - #configuring..................................................................
ruby-3.2.1 - #post-configuration..
ruby-3.2.1 - #compiling.......................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1677498306_ruby-3.2.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Below is the output of make.log

```
[2023-02-27 05:45:41] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-3.2.1
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin:/root/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global
command(2): __rvm_make -j4
--bash,383+ make -j4
    BASERUBY = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = gcc -std=gnu99
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -std=gnu99 -shared
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized   -fPIC 
    XCFLAGS = -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/15.0.0 
    CPPFLAGS =   
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.3.2  -fstack-protector  
    SOLIBS =  -lz -lrt -lrt -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm -lpthread 
    LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
    MFLAGS = - --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j
    RUSTC = no
    YJIT_RUSTC_ARGS = --crate-name=yjit --crate-type=staticlib --edition=2021 -g -C opt-level=3 -C overflow-checks=on '--out-dir=/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-3.2.1/yjit/target/release/' ./yjit/src/lib.rs

compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
making dummy probes.h
compiling ast.c
In file included from ./include/ruby/internal/intern/class.h:24,
                 from ./include/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:76,
                 from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:27,
                 from dmydln.c:1:
./include/ruby/internal/value.h:128: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constantIn file included from ./include/ruby/internal/intern/class.h:24,
                 from ./include/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:76,
                 from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:27,
                 from internal.h:31,
                 from ast.c:2:
```

I tried the stable RVM and did rvm install ruby 3.2.1, it did not work too.
The node is on OEL 6 and RVM 1.29.12
Could someone help is fixing this error and installing ruby 3.2.1

Comment: The block you posted includes a giant, blaring warning right at the top that you don't have RVM setup correctly. Did you fix that? Then even though it proceeds with the installation it reports an error by saying `please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1677498306_ruby-3.2.1/make.log`. Did you read the log like it said? Why didn't you include that log in this post? I have downvoted this question because *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. I have voted to close this question because *This question should include more details and clarify the problem.*

Comment: I had issues with adding the logs. I've trimmed the logs so that the system let me post them

Comment: next few lines of the make.log
In file included from ./include/ruby/internal/intern/class.h:24,
                 from ./include/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:76,
                 from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:27,
                 from dmydln.c:1:
./include/ruby/internal/value.h:128: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
./include/ruby/internal/value.h:128: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant

Answer (score 59):

First check the which openssl has been installed in your system.

```
which openssl
```

Try to find out the path of openssl directory. In my case it was in `/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1`

```
cd /usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1
```

Now run the command

```
rvm install ruby-3.2.1 -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. same approach fixed a bug i was having installing 3.2.2 with rvm

Comment: Nice, is  working

Comment: Someone get this dude a beer

Comment: tried all solutions, even with `rvm pkg install openssl`. This is the only one which worked for 2.7.8

Comment: Can someone explain how did we arrive at openssl as the issue. I'm new to backend stuffs so just curious on how you guys are debugging.

Answer (score 20):

While installing the ruby on latest version of Ubuntu 22.04, I encountered a common problem when trying to install Ruby with RVM. However, I was able to resolve this issue by executing the following command:

`rvm install ruby-3.2.1 -C --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local/libexec/openssl11`

In case OpenSSL is not installed, you can refer to this [comprehensive guide](https://blog.francium.tech/setting-up-ruby-2-7-6-on-ubuntu-22-04-fdb9560715f7) for installing Ruby version 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 22.04

The root cause of the problem stems from the fact that Ubuntu 22.04 only provides OpenSSL 3.0, which is only supported by some latest Ruby versions 3.1 and above. You can find more details on this issue on [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1940#discussioncomment-2663209)

i was also facing the similar issue on my mac OS which i fixed by not using the `openssl@3` which by default install it work with the `oppenssl@2.8.3` on mac as well otherwise we get similr issue `_rvm_make-j` on the mac as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain what was (possibly) going on under the hood. I love when an explanation is included in an answer and not just the -sadly- typical _copy/paste this and off you go_

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with ruby-3.1.2. I followed these instructions:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew reinstall openssl@3
rvm install ruby-3.1.2 --reconfigure --enable-yjit --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
```

This link provides more details (Investigation by the one and only BrianHawley):
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5365

Answer (score 3):

To clarify and expand a bit:

The `which openssl` command gives you the path of the openssl binary in your system. For example, if you've installed OpenSSL using Homebrew, you might get a path like `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl`

When installing Ruby with rvm, you can specify custom configuration options using the `-C` flag. One of these options is `--with-openssl-dir`, which tells `rvm` where to find OpenSSL on your system

```
rvm install ruby-3.2.1 -C --with-openssl-dir=/path/to/your/openssl
```

Replace `/path/to/your/openssl` with the actual path obtained from which openssl

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved this error, I realized that the project i'm working on does not support my version of openssl. it wasversion 3.2.0. I needed to step it down to version 1.1.
And i got this prompt when i ran  `cat/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb`

the result was

```
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for LIBRESSL_VERSION_NUMBER in openssl/opensslv.h... no
checking for OpenSSL version >= 1.0.1 and < 3.0.0... no
Traceback (most recent call last):
extconf.rb:111:in `<main>': OpenSSL >= 1.0.1, < 3.0.0 or LibreSSL 
>= 2.5.0 is required (RuntimeError)
```

then i ran

```
brew update
brew upgrade openssl
```

after i cd into the openssl. Next i checked the version

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023)
```

to switch to 1.1 which i already had i did

```
brew unlink openssl@3
brew link openssl@1.1
```

I checked my version again and got

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Per this issue at [RVM's github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5379), this command worked on my MacBook running Sonoma 14.2 with an Intel chip:

```
rvm reinstall 3.2.0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline) --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml) --disable-dtrace --disable-docs
```

It sets your OpenSSL directory without explicitly looking it up and copying it into the subsequent command

Answer (score 0):

I was installing ruby 3.0.2 and it worked with this command

```
rvm install ruby-3.0.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin/openssl
```

I checked my SSL version with

```
openssl version
```

it gave me OpenSSL 3.0.2, but didn't work when I specified this version with SSL
, to check where you have installed SSL you can do

```
 which openssl
```

in my case it gave me /usr/bin/openssl